# Why does it not work properly media query?

Tags: css, media-queries

When I write max-width(1220px) it works when width is 1300px and when I write second breakpoint 1150px now from 1300px works only 1150px and ignored 1220px

HTML CODE

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="left">arrow left</div>
        <div class="right">arrow right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

STYLE CODE

```
.container {
width: 1600px;
margin: auto;
}
.inner {
position: relative;
}
.left,
.right {
position: absolute;
}
.left {
    left: -50px
}
.right {
    left: 300px
}
@media (max-width: 1220px) {
    .right {
        left: 250px
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1150px) {
    .right {
        left: 210px
    }
}
```

you can see the image description here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7viiX.jpg

Comment: Please post the CSS and a the simplest HMTL that reproduces your problem not just a link to some picture/image (which many will NEVER view)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`max-width: 1220px` media query applies on devices with the width of `1220px` or smaller, same thing happens for `max-width: 1150`.

This is what should happen in your code with both breakpoints:

- When device width greater than `1220px` --> `.right { left: 300px; }`
- When device width smaller than `1220px` and greater than `1150px` --> `.right { left: 250px; }`
- when device width is smaller than `1150px` --> `.right { left: 210px; }`

Comment: Yes, but did I write the same thing?  I do not understand the problem, I guess how it works but I can not understand why it works